# How to determine which set of integers is "lower"

Tags: set, discrete-mathematics

I'm doing a coding challenge, and part of the problem requires me to determine which set of integers has the lowest numbers.

"If there are multiple sets of the same size, return the set of with the lowest IDs (as indexes) in sorted order."

The problem I seem to be facing is how to decide which set has the lowest numbers.  For instance, if I have {1, 4} and {2, 3}, which one would I return?

I've tried basic things like returning the one with the lowest minimum or lowest maximum, returning the one with the lowest sum, product, average, etc. I've even tried merging the sets. My results still fail the test cases.

This is one part of an advanced challenge, so the answer may lie in discreet math or combinatorics, but I am not familiar enough with those fields.

Comment: If you are doing a coding challenge, which language are you using?

Comment: Java.  I don't think I need code, just a direction to search in.

Comment: Could you ad the test case and the correct answer? Or the complete problem discripion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406039/google-foobar-maximum-unique-visits-under-a-resource-limit-negative-weights-in  That's the problem description.  I have no access to the test cases or the answers, I only know which test cases I get right or wrong.  I am at the point where I can get some right if I choose one way, and others right if I choose a different way, but I can't get them all right at the same time.

Comment: There must be another problem with my code, and I'm barking up the wrong tree...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!  Apparently, they were simply looking for the set that started with the lowest number.  I had a different bug in my that was confusing me and making me think the problem was in which set to return.

In short, I was using a Hashtable to store all possible states and the fastest times to reach that state.  But the way I had it coded, the same Hashtable was getting reused in all the tests.  States were not getting properly updated because they already existed in the table from a previous test.